# Git checkout with several remotes

Tags: git, git-checkout

I am really confused about how git checkout would work.

Let's say I have two remotes:

```
origin
alternative
```

Let's say both remotes have a branch called master.

What would happen if I do git checkout master? Would I be checking out the master of origin or the master of alternative?  How would I change to the other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git checkout master
```

Grabs checks out the local branch named master.

```
git checkout -b NEWBRANCHNAME1 origin/master
git checkout -b NEWBRANCHNAME2 alternative/master
```

Would create local branches that you can work on.

Comment: But that local branch named master is going to be associated with some remote, right?

Comment: @HommerSmith It will be associated with the one you created it from. If you did `git clone some-repo.git`, then `origin` will point to `some-repo.git`, and `master` will track `origin/master`. If you created it with `git checkout -t -b`, then it will track the branch that you created it from. You can change which branches track which others in your `.git/config`.